# Couple of Questions about Firebase security

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security

I started learning about Firebase for an android, but still can't get my head around some stuff, so I have couple of questions that I would love your help to answer.

1 - Can a user (or a hacker) know my firebase link from the app?

2 - if they did, will they be able to change my stored data without knowing my google email address associated with the database?

Thanks

Comment: Let me know if my answered work for you. If so please mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless properly secured, anyone can read or write data to your Firebase database.

**To secure your Firebase database you need to write [Security Rules](http://firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html).**

Firebase Security Rules live on a Firebase server and validate whether someone can access your data.

You also might want to check out this answer too for [a beginner explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34021853/1373162).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but the question is it possible for others to know my firebase link from my app?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but if you write Security Rules then it doesn't matter.